# Why are changes made in my .NET MVC-4 solution not showing in the browser preview?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, solution

So I'm running Visual Studio 2012 (Win7) on VMWare Fusion. About 50% of the time a change to a view would not render in the browser preview. This would drive me crazy. The solution I found would be to simply kill the WebView.WebServer40 app that launches when you click View In Browser for a web build. Seems to be an issue with working on a Mac virtual machine, as running on a PC doesn't have this issue. If anyone else has a better solution to this that would be great. It's an annoying workflow but at least I'm yelling at it.

--

## Update

If anyone comes across this, found a solution here: [caching in asp.net development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072668/caching-in-asp-net-development-server)

Also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911272

Edit a registry key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\DefaultDocumentInstalled from 1 to 2

--

## Update #2

So that fix only worked for a moment and may have just a quirk. For me installing IIS Express via the Microsoft Web Platform Installer worked magic. No more issue. Jesus.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=WebMatrix

Comment: I just use IIS Express http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview

Comment: Thanks man, that actually was the winning ticket. The first hack stopped working for me.